# Chrome extension: sending message from background.js to content.js whenever current tab URL changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, listener

I am trying to send a message from `background.js` to `content.js` every time the current tab's URL changes (either via reload on non-reload).

In **background.js**, I add a listener for tab updates, filter for the current active window, and send a message:

```
/*global chrome*/
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    
    if (changeInfo.url) {            
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hi"}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }); 
          
      }
});
```

In **content.js**, I add a onMessage listener to check for this message:

```
/*global chrome*/
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("runtime", request);
    if (request.message === 'hi') {
        console.log('I am from content script: ', request.message);
        sendResponse("goodbye");
    }
})
```

However, this does not seem to work. When I remove the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` and only have:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hi"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

then it works for whatever reason. So I believe the error is in the use of the onUpdated listener.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When a URL changes the tab starts loading the new page, then your sendMessage runs, then the page loads and the content script runs at DOMContentLoaded (by default) so it won't receive the message. It's unclear what you want to achieve with this code because the content script already knows the new URL as `location.href`.

Comment: Here is my actual intent: I would like to get the URL in background.js whenever the URL changes, then call a Python function (text parser) on this url, and finally send the resulting string output as a message to a React component, let's say `App.js`. I know this is slightly tangential to the question, but I assumed if I could do it for `content.js`, I should be able to do it for `App.js` @wOxxOm

Comment: Assuming you want to run the parser on html, you can reverse the flow: let the content script send the data e.g. chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.documentElement.innerHTML), which will be received in the background script's chrome.runtime.onMessage, which will call your python code.